# error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'lowest' used

Tags: c++

I have a problem I cant figure out. I am kinda new to programming. Here is the code I have written. and here is the error i am getting "error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'lowest' used " Im not sure how to fix it. Also Im sure there are better ways to writ this program, but this is the requirements I have to go by. How do I fix the error im getting?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void getScore(int &score);
int findLowest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5, int &lowest);
void calcAverage(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5);


int main ()
{
cout<<"Average with Lowest Score Drop by John\n"<<endl; 
int score1, 
    score2, 
    score3, 
    score4, 
    score5,
    lowest;

    getScore(score1);
    getScore(score2);
    getScore(score3);
    getScore(score4);
    getScore(score5);

    calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);


    cin.get();
    cin.get();
return 0;
}

void getScore(int &score)
{

cout << "Please enter 5 test scores between 1 and 100): ";
cin >> score;

while (score <= 0 || score >= 100)
{
    cout << "Enter a score values of 0 to 100";
    cin >> score;
}
}

int findLowest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5, int &lowest)
{
lowest = score1;
if (score2 < lowest)
    lowest = score2;
else if (score3 < lowest)
    lowest = score3;
else if (score4 < lowest)
    lowest = score4;
else if (score5 < lowest)
    lowest = score5;

cout << "The lowest test score is " << lowest << endl;

return lowest;
}

void calcAverage (int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)

{
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int, int);
int lowest;
double average;
 findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, lowest);


average = (((float)score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) - lowest) / 4.0;
//cout << setw(4);
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
cout <<" With the grade "<<lowest<< " dropped"<<"The average of test scores entered is: " << average << endl;
}
```

Comment: At least tell us which line the error occurs on. Also, have you tried simplifying the program to the shortest program that still contains the error?

Comment: Don't put function prototypes inside functions.

Comment: One day soon, you'll learn to use arrays instead of sets of variables like `score1`, `score2`, ... `score5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findLowest` prototype inside `calcAverage` is missing `&`:

```
void calcAverage (int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)
{
    int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int, int&);
    //                                         ^
    ....
}
```

Actually, you don't need that prototype, because there's already same prototype before the `main` function.

Comment: But you really should just remove that prototype, since it's unneeded, and unneeded redundancy is just a source of errors, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon your question. The answer seems obvious. Take a look at your last lines:`
    void calcAverage (int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)

```
{
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int, int);
int lowest;
double average;
 findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, lowest);


average = (((float)score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) - lowest) / 4.0;
//cout << setw(4);
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
cout <<" With the grade "<<lowest<< " dropped"<<"The average of test scores entered is: " << average << endl;
} `
```

Here `int lowest` is not initialized.
Try to write `int lowest(0);` or a similar initial value that suits your needs.